# Knockout.js carraige return in paragraph text

Tags: knockout.js, carriage-return, paragraph

Using knockout.js, how do I include a carriage return in the text that is bound to the text attribute of a paragraph `<p>` element.

In my ViewModel I generated a string of text that is bound to the `<p>` in the View. I want to include carriage returns in the string which the browser displays with the line breaks.

Including `<br />` or `Environment.NewLine` in the string does not seem to work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [html binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html).

JS:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "Bert<br\>Test";
    this.lastName = "Bertington";
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

View :

```
<p>First name: <strong data-bind="html: firstName">todo</strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong>todo</strong></p>
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qZtLd/)

Comment: if you're going to do this, make sure to encode any content that isn't already HTML encoded

Comment: Thanks, the data-bind="html: ..." is what did it for me

Answer (score 62):

You need to set a css property in your element. [`white-space: pre-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

```
<p style="white-space: pre-wrap">First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName">todo</strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong>todo</strong></p>

function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "Bert" + " \n " + "Test";
    this.lastName = "Bertington";
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Then the code works. with `\n`

Comment: I think this solution is much better because there is no html characters specific to html in the javascript.

Comment: Definitely a better solution, especially where the data is user edited data, the HTML solution would require the use of a WYSIWYG editor which is completely unnecessary