# Creating a custom binding for nl2br in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, custom-binding

I am trying to write a custom binding to replace "`/n`" with "`<br />`"  within a "`<p>`" element.

I understand the concept more or less, but I'm stuggling to get it going. Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong. I don't really want to use a computed observable, as I want to keep the real value using "`/n`" rather than "`<br />`".

```
ko.bindingHandlers.nl2br = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var field = valueAccessor();
        field.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
        $(element).val(field)
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var field = valueAccessor();
        field.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
        $(element).val(field)
    }
};
```

Comment: For anyone who just needs to ***visually*** get new lines where a \n character is in the text: this is **possible with one css-property** - see the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422895/knockout-js-carraige-return-in-paragraph-text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TL;DR Answer

```
ko.bindingHandlers.nl2br = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var field = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        field = field.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
        ko.bindingHandlers.html.update(element, function() { return field; });
    }
};
```

---

## Full Answer

First things first, the `replace` call should probably be:

```
field = field.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```

Otherwise the new string gets discarded.

Apart from that, I wouldn't recommend setting the element value like that directly. Rely on the existing handlers (that presumably are well tested in various browsers) to do the heavy lifting. See [R.P. Niemeyer's blog post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html) on the subject (specifically item 3).

You can use either the [the `text` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html) which will *literally* render "`<br />`" or (if you trust the input!) [the `html` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html) if you want to render a newline for the `<br />`. The latter looks like this:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.nl2br = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var field = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        field = field.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
        ko.bindingHandlers.html.update(element, function() { return field; });
    }
};

ko.applyBindings({ description: ko.observable("This is\nSparta!") });
```

```css
p, pre { background-color: #dde; margin: 4px 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<strong>Text version in &lt;p&gt;:</strong>
<p data-bind="text: description"></p>
<hr />
<strong>Text version &lt;pre&gt;:</strong>
<pre data-bind="text: description"></pre>
<hr />
<strong>NL2BR version in &lt;p&gt;:</strong>
<p data-bind="nl2br: description"></p>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention my value was an observable, needed to call itself as a function to return the value. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Wellso It's better in that case to use `unwrapObservable`, see [this advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624401/when-to-use-ko-utils-unwrapobservable). My answer was lacking in that regard, I've updated it accordingly.