# Extend text binding in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is it possible to extend the `text` binding in knockout with additional options?  For example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.text = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor){
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().textOptions || {};
        options = _.extend({
            'required': false
        }, options);
        if(options['required']){
            // Do some required things
        }
    }
};
```

So then a text binding could be written as:

```html
<span data-bind="text: myText, textOptions: { required: true }" />
```

Is this possible or would a custom binding be required?

Comment: Beware that `span` is *not* allowed to be a self-closing element. Weird things in some browsers may happen if you don't create a regular open+close.

Answer (score 4):

For wrapping existing bindings, see section 3 [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html). The gist is that in the `init` section, you call `ko.bindingHandlers.text.init` and similarly for `update`. Around those calls, you can do anything else you like. If the binding you're wrapping doesn't have one of init or update, you'll get an error, and you can just remove that call.

Comment: Ah yesss of course, +1, that's a good option too. [I've even suggested the same in the past](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18124635/419956) for a scenario with the `html` binding. Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, that's not *extending* the `text` binding, you're *overwriting* it.

First things first, note that currently the `text` binding is extremely simple. Taken from [the source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/text.js):

```
ko.bindingHandlers['text'] = {
    'init': function() {
        // Prevent binding on the dynamically-injected text node (as developers are unlikely to expect that, and it has security implications).
        // It should also make things faster, as we no longer have to consider whether the text node might be bindable.
        return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': true };
    },
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.setTextContent(element, valueAccessor());
    }
};
```

The actual functionality is offloaded to `setTextContent`, which handles cross-browser setting of, well, text content.

If you want to have a binding that does things similar to `text`, only with some added features, the easiest way probably *is* to create a custom binding handler yourself that utilizes `setTextContent`. For example:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers['myText'] = {
    'init': function() {
        return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': true };
    },
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()), txt = '';
        if (value !== null && typeof value == "object") {
            txt = value['text'];
            if (!!value['required']) { txt += "!!!"; }
          
        } else {
            txt = value;
        }
        ko.utils.setTextContent(element, txt);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings({ testProperty: "test text 1234" });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<span data-bind="myText: { text: testProperty, required: true }"></span>
<br>
<span data-bind="myText: { text: testProperty, required: false }"></span>
<br>
<span data-bind="myText: testProperty"></span>
```